# Reduce the size of a .MDF file when deleting data through Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to shrink manually the size of a `.mdf` file from the Entity Framework, or at least turn on the Auto Shrink option?

I've read in some places that it is not recommended, but that is a customer requirement (*to reduce the size of the file when data is deleted*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an EF task/issue. It is a SQL Server maintenance task. You are correct when you shrink the files/database you leave your data fragmented. You would want to defragment immediately after.

I would not recommend making this a common behavior. Unless you are doing VERY large deletes the amount of space reclaimed is probably negligible. If you do need to shrink I would plan during low volume/down time and do the defragment as well.

I would inform your customer of this nature of this task and build a normal maintenance schedule to perform these types of DB activities. This would be a best practice approach.

Comment: Okay, but to do the maintenance, how could I do that? Should I create a script (in C#, for example) to do that task? The problem is that I don't have access to his computer (we're not living in the same country).

Comment: No, create a scheduled SQL task of a maintenance plan. This is SQL work and should not need to involve .NET at all. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188432.aspx

Comment: But how could I do that from my computer? I mean, could I build a SQL script in my computer and send it to him so he can execute it or something like that?

Comment: Here is the command `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (DBNAME)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Connect to database via standard `SqlConnection` and execute required operations. EF is not intended for this.